# Different firing angles of SCR

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier, scr

[image]

Considering this circuit, what would happen if T<sub>1</sub> and T<sub>2</sub> had different firing angles, let's say 45° for T<sub>1</sub> and 60° for T<sub>2</sub>?

Is it the same thing as both of them having 60°? (I think that the circuit is not closed until the second SCR is not fired up).

Comment: `circuit is not closed` ... what does this mean? ... *conducting* or *not conducting*

Answer (score 0):

The negative half wave of secondary voltage will be rectified by D1 & D2, and the positive polarity will be controlled by T1 & T2.

In case the  T1 gate voltage is held (or is a long enough pulse train) after 45º, output current will flow when T2 is switched on (60º). But if T1 gate is activated by a short pulse at 45º, there will be no current to hold T1 switched on because T2 is off; in this condition, when T2 is activated at 60º, no current will flow because T1 is already off.

If you "fire" both T1 & T2 at 60º, current will be established at that angle.